# Don't let moderators be chatroom owners

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderators, chat-flags

I would like to suggest the following, network wide, change in policy concerning the ownership of chatrooms:

No moderator should be a chatroom owner.

This, I believe, would be a more efficient use  of the experienced members of the community who frequently use the rooms and therefore, have more knowledge about the context of the rooms than a moderator who is busy with other duties. Also it would be a more "hands-on" approach to governing the politics and various flag issues that occur there.

Since moderators already have all the privileges of a room owner; it is *redundant* to have them on the list of room owners.

Comment: Moderators are not owners, they just have same power as result of their overall super privileges. What you suggest is take away some of those privileges, which I (and many others here) oppose.

Comment: I am **not** suggesting to take-away anyone's powers, all I am saying is that no moderator should be on the list of a chat room's owner.

Comment: That too, is a terrible suggestion. A moderator is a community member first, they are entitled to have every privilege a normal registered user has.

Comment: That is even worse, @skullpatrol. Being actual room owner is only formal for moderator since he/she already gets all associated powers, so really pointless to deny it from them.

Comment: It is **redunant** to have a mod as a room owner.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In terms of moderation privileges, sure, it's redundant, but it's not redundant in marking who considers themselves "responsible" (in some sense) for maintaining the chat room. Occasionally it's useful for someone wandering into a chat room to know who is "in charge" of that room - in other words, who should be the point(s) of contact for questions about events associated with the room, the standards to which discussion in the room should be held, and so on. That won't necessarily be a moderator, but it could be.

Even if I, as a moderator, enter an unfamiliar chat room, I'll often defer to the room owner on these matters because even though I have moderation powers, I don't know how best to use them to maintain the environment that is expected in that room.

Besides, is it really doing any harm to allow moderators to be room owners? I don't think so. This strikes me as a "too minor" feature-request in the sense that it adds complexity to the system without solving any problem, as far as I can tell.

Comment: What I am suggesting here is a form of self-government. Since, the system records and graphs the activity of all the users in the room, why not choose the room owner based on that data, rather than the current system? If you want to be a room owner it is only fair that you should actively participate in that room.

Comment: @skullpatrol okay, but that's entirely different from what you posted in your question.

Comment: Should I edit the question to reflect this?

Comment: @skullpatrol no, that would be too much of a change. It would invalidate the existing answer. Ask a new question instead if you want to make that proposal. Though you should search first to see if it's already been suggested. I think there's a good chance it has been.

Answer (score -5):

The only real answer to my question comes from a compromise which uses the following argument. What I am suggesting here is a form of self-government.

Since, the system records and graphs the activity of all the users in the room, why not choose the room owner based on that data, rather than the current system?

If you want to be a room owner it is only fair that you should actively participate in that room.

This kind of change in the system would make full use of those who are most likely to be actually in the room and participating during flagging of comments, temporary banning, etc.

Comment: This sounds like a different feature request. What you post in this answer is unrelated to banning mods from room-ownership as presented in the question.